# Can the size of a signed integer type differ from that of its corresponding unsigned type in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

For example, can an implementation define `sizeof(signed int)` to be two bytes and `sizeof(unsigned int)` to be four bytes? I wasn't able to find anything explicitly forbidding this in the C/C++ [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), though the minimum sizes of the signed and unsigned versions of types correspond, and I can't see any logical reason why their sizes should ever be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can the size of a signed integer type differ from that of its corresponding unsigned type in C/C++?

No.  For C, `int` and `unsigned` have the same *size*.  Confident C++ inherits the same specification.

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword `unsigned`) that **uses the same amount of storage** (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.
>   C11dr §6.2.5 6

Comment: I checked, and this is correct. The current C++ standard uses the same verbiage.

Comment: Maybe is worth to mention C implements BCD (Binary-coded Decimal) to encode decimal numbers. This has more to do with BCD and CPU architecture than C specifics. OP didn't find anything relating this in C/C++ specifics because it is an assumption on the language side I guess.

Comment: However, corresponding signed and unsigned integers do not need to use the same number of bits to represent values. C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 allows padding bits in signed integers other than `signed char`, so the size of the range of a signed integer may be less than the size of the range of the corresponding unsigned integer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True.  Further, a limiting spec is that `INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX`, not the often assumed `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX/2`.  Padding in `int/unsigned` is certainly rare these days.  IME, only have seen padding in a select case years ago involving the widest integer type available.

Comment: @dedecos: No, that's not worth mentioning because it's not true. The C standard doesn't mention BCD, and in fact it requires a pure binary representation for both signed and unsigned integer types. (Some implementations might support BCD types as an extension.)

Comment: @KeithThompson hmm good to know that. I thought BDC was something that cpu architectures implemented, and as a given C compiler being developed to these architectures, it would have to encode decimals using BDC. So there is no relation between cpu architecture and BDC? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: @dedecos: Some CPUs do implement BCD, but the C standard doesn't support them. But as I said, some C *compilers* might support them as an extension.

Comment: @dedecos C explicitly allows 3 forms of signed formats: two's complement, one's complement and signed magnitude. Signed BCD isn't one of them, and apparently signed BCD is poorly standardized in general.

Comment: The C++ standards do have a similar clause.   In C++98, this is Section 3.9.1 "Fundamental types", para 3, which says "For each of the signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) *unsigned integer type*: “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”, and “`unsigned long int`,” each of which occupies the same amount of storage and has the same alignment requirements (3.9) as the corresponding signed integer type".   Subsequent C++ standard have clauses with similar meaning but (from memory) slightly different wording and section numbering.